# apt update failing unless I use a VPN

Tags: apt, updates, vpn

I've had a persistent issue with not being able to run `sudo apt update` *unless* I activate a VPN, in which case it runs fine. This behaviour has been persistent from at least 22.04, just upgraded to 23.04 and still there.

Error messages I receive are:

```
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lunar-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

A possibly related symptom is that in the top right of the screen where it shows your network connection, it's showing a `?` over the wifi symbol.

I've tried ethernet and wifi on my home network as well as using a hotspot.

I have tried various suggested solutions from searching around including editing my `/etc/apt/sources.list` , changing the server location, nothing has worked so far.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like it's trying to connect over IPv6. Does your ISP provide a valid IPv6 address? If not, disable IPv6 on your network settings, and that might sort it.

Comment: @popey unfortunately that hasn't worked for me. Any other ideas?